# Tunneling to an internal corporate SSH server behind a gateway

Tags: ssh, gateway, tunnel

I am trying to do the following.  I have an internal ssh server at work (e.g. internal@192.168.1.13).  This server is behind a gateway (external@gateway.work.com).

I would like to ssh to internal@internal-ssh.work.com from my home machine.  To do so, I have been first doing ssh to log into the external gateway, and then from there I will log into the internal machine.  the account names on the two systems are different.

I was wondering if this can be done in one step through some type of SSH tunneling.  I have tried a few approaches that adapt what I see in different places, but keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
ssh -t external@gateway.work.com ssh internal@192.168.1.13
```

and you will need to either have public key crypto set up, or enter your external password, then your internal password.